# How to apply Css transition delay property to change image after certain time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I'm trying to select the image using its id and changing the image after  5 seconds, but the transition delay is not working is there anything I'm doing wrong could someone please let me know as I feel this is an important question no one ever bothered to ask

```js
var b1=document.querySelector("#bubbles");
   b1.src="https://steemitimages.com/DQmaC34qT4WKoUd9A1X91XjGVRbCYEJZooCJxwshpvjvpnU/3676223822_713fe300a6_b.jpg";
   
    b1.style.transitionDelay="5s";
    
    b1.src="http://earthwidetribe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/popping-bubble.jpg";
    
     b1.style.transitionDelay="5s";
     
   b1.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-wGqzB-SJZnFzXoKnSRjRK5IDLgYY43GpLG1FXj5uvgivbMtT";
```

```html
<img id="bubbles"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transitionDelay will only delay the display of the element. your code will all run at once so the last transitionDelay and src will be applied to the element.

Do this instead:

```js
var b1 = document.querySelector("#bubbles");
b1.src = "https://steemitimages.com/DQmaC34qT4WKoUd9A1X91XjGVRbCYEJZooCJxwshpvjvpnU/3676223822_713fe300a6_b.jpg";

setTimeout(function() {
  b1.src = "http://earthwidetribe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/popping-bubble.jpg";

  setTimeout(function() {
    b1.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-wGqzB-SJZnFzXoKnSRjRK5IDLgYY43GpLG1FXj5uvgivbMtT";
  }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<img id="bubbles" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate src with css
you can fadeout and change src then fadein